# is there a way to find duplicated value that has both the same address and pickup date in two different table?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am currently working on a delivery app. Basically, what I am trying to achieve here is to have a counter that display out any potential duplicated jobs that the customer might have accidently double entered.

The criteria to be considered as a duplicated job is as such:

1. Has to have same delivery_address and same pickup_date.

This is my postgresql tables:

```
class Order(models.Model):
    id_order = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

```
class OrderDelivery(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    delivery_address = models.TextField()
```

```
class OrderPickup(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    pickup_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
```

This is what I have came up with so far:

```
def dashboard_duplicated_job(orders, month):

    # This function finds for jobs that has
    # (1) exact pickup_date
    # (2) exact delivery address
    # and mark it as duplicated job.

    # Find current month, if not take current year
    now = timezone.localtime(timezone.now())
    month = "12" if month and int(month) == 0 else month

    if month == 12 or month == '12':
        now = timezone.localtime(timezone.now())
        last_month = now.today() + relativedelta(months=-1)
        start_date = last_month.replace(day=1).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

        year = last_month.replace(day=1).strftime('%Y')
        month = last_month.replace(day=1).strftime('%m')
        last_day = calendar.monthrange(int(year), int(month))[1]

        string_start = str(year) + "-" + str(month) + "-01"
        string_end = str(year) + "-" + str(month) + "-" + str(last_day)

        start_date = datetime.strptime(string_start + " 00:00:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        end_date = datetime.strptime(string_end + " 23:59:59", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    else:
        year = now.year
        last = calendar.monthrange(year, int(month))[1]

        string_start = str(year) + "-" + str(month) + "-01"
        string_end = str(year) + "-" + str(month) + "-" + str(last)

        start_date = datetime.strptime(string_start + " 00:00:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        end_date = datetime.strptime(string_end + " 23:59:59", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")


    # Filter pickup_date of Orderpickup to display only orders related to current month
    opu = OrderPickup.objects.filter(
        order_id__in=orders,
        pickup_date__range=(start_date, end_date)
    ).values(
        'order_id',
        'pickup_date',
    )

    # Filter OrderDelivery based on pickup_date range
    ods = OrderDelivery.objects.filter(
        order_id__in=opu.values('order_id')
    ).values(
        'order_id',
        'delivery_address',
        # 'reference_no'
    )

    # Find duplicated delivery_address
    dup_ods = ods.values(
        'delivery_address'
    ).annotate(
        duplicated_delivery_address=Count('delivery_address')
    ).filter(
        duplicated_delivery_address__gt=1
    )

    # Extract the IDs of the duplicated delivery_address from dup_ods
    dup_ods_id = ods.filter(
        delivery_address__in=[item['delivery_address'] for item in dup_ods]
    ).values(
        'order_id'
    )

    # Find duplicated pickup_date based on duplicated_address <not working as intended>
    dup_opu = opu.filter(
        order_id__in=dup_ods_id
    ).values(
        'pickup_date'
    ).annotate(
        duplicated_pickup_date=Count('pickup_date')
    ).filter(
        duplicated_pickup_date__gt=1
    )

    dup_opu_id = opu.filter(
        pickup_date__in=[item['pickup_date'] for item in dup_opu]
    ).order_by()

    orders = orders.filter(id_order__in=dup_opu_id)

    return orders
```

Based on what I have came up with, I am having situation where orders that has same delivery_address but different pickup_date is showing up.

example (correct):
| delivery_address | pickup_date|
| -------- | -------------- |
| here    | 08-03-2022            |
| here   | 08-03-2022            |
| there| 09-03-2022            |
| there  | 09-03-2022            |

example (incorrect, currently displaying):
| delivery_address | pickup_date|
| -------- | -------------- |
| here    | 08-03-2022            |
| here   | 08-03-2022            |
| here   | 09-03-2022            |
| there| 09-03-2022            |
| there  | 09-03-2022            |

Please advise thank you.

**UPDATE**

I have managed to solve my problem. Below is my solution:

```
dup_job = orders.filter(
        orderpickup__pickup_date__range=(start_date, end_date)
    ).values(
        'id_order',
        'orderdelivery__delivery_address',
        'orderpickup__pickup_date'
    ).annotate(
        duplicated=Count('orderdelivery__delivery_address')
    ).filter(
        duplicated__gt=1
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

I have managed to solve my problem. Below is my solution:

```
dup_job = orders.filter(
        orderpickup__pickup_date__range=(start_date, end_date)
    ).values(
        'id_order',
        'orderdelivery__delivery_address',
        'orderpickup__pickup_date'
    ).annotate(
        duplicated=Count('orderdelivery__delivery_address')
    ).filter(
        duplicated__gt=1
    )
```